# How to combine features extracted by PCA, LDA and LBP?

Tags: pca, discriminant-analysis, image-processing

What I'm thinking is to combine PCA features, LDA features and [LBP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns) features together to get a higher accuracy, since I think the three features are all kind of histogram vectors and when we decide the label of a test image, we compare the histogram of the test image to the histograms of existing images. So is it possible to combine the feature vectors together?

However I think the feature histogram of LBP is very long. If we use 8-by-8 grids then the histogram will be $8\times 8\times 256 = 16384$ long. And the eigenface weight vectors are of the length of how many eigenface components we choose, say 80. So I'm not sure whether we can do this.

I'll keep thinking on this and any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them - On the purely technical level by concatenating them all together and feeding them as features. (Assuming you did each transformation seperately). 
You could also do each transformation on the product of the previous one, though I don't know if this makes any sense or is better or even sound. (I.E - PCA on the original features, then LDA on the PCA..)